# How implement copy constructor for shared data

Tags: c++, copy-constructor

I need to implement the **copy constructor** of a class.

My requirements is that all the objects need to share the same data. 
Example: if I change the name of one object, all the others object get the new object name.

This is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Contact
{
public:
    string name;

    //Constructor:
    Contact(string n){
        name = n;
    };

    /*
    // Copy constructor:
    */
};

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {

    Contact c1("albert");
    Contact c2 = c1; //create a copy of c1

    c1.name = "mark"; //modify c1 name

    cout << c2.name << endl; //My problem: I want this output is "mark"

    return 0;
}
```

It is possible do it with pointers?

I try this code but I get the error:
*"error: lvalue required as left operand of assignment"*

```
// Copy constructor:
Contact (const Contact &c){
    &( this -> name ) = &c.name;
}
```

Comment: You don't need a copy constructor, you just need to make `name` static. But the chances of this being a good design choice are quite small.

Comment: Sounds like a perfect use case for `std::shared_ptr`.

Comment: Why would you want that?

Comment: It is an interview question.

Answer (score 1):

> if I change the name of one object, all the others object get the new object name.

That is a strange requirement. It does not make sense that all the instances of a class have the same name.

Disregarding the propriety of the requirement, the requirement indicates that you need some piece of data that is independent of instances of the class. It can be either a `static` member variable of the class or a global variable, preferably scoped to a namespace.

```
class Contact
{
   public:

      static std::string name;

      //Constructor:
      Contact(){}

      // Copy constructor:
};
```

or

```
namespace MyApp
{
   // Make sure to define it in an appropriate .cpp file.
   extern std::string contact_name;

   class Contact
   {
      public:

         //Constructor:
         Contact(){}

         // Copy constructor:
   };
}
```